# Forwarded OTRS messages

Tags: otrs

If anyone has encountered such a problem, please tell me where OTRS stores the flags of messages that have been forwarded to other responsible persons?

I wrote a bot that sends telegram messages about opening and closing tickets, now I am asked to send notifications about forwarding. I didn't find anything similar to what I need in the database (PostgreSQL).  Moreover, there is nothing on this topic in the documentation